InvalidTokenError: Invalid Compact JWS (Auth0 with ReactJS and NodeJs Express)
tried reading the similar issues in auth0 community and stack overflow but it doesn't fix my problem.  So trying to create myself questions and direct ask here.
the real-estate-api is the Custom API i create under applications->APIs, that's the API audience.
the client id im using in react js is the SPA one: 
i keep getting  Invalid Compact JWS. Execution is on postman by the way. Provided the steps i made in postman as well below
also, i made some testing in jwt.io, im getting the sub, the aud and the iss properly: 
Using the latest versions for auth0 in react and on nodejs the oauth2
React JS:
import { Auth0Provider, useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

function LoginButton() {
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() =>
        loginWithRedirect({
          authorizationParams: {
            scope: "read:current_user email",
            screen_hint: "signin",
          },
        })
      }
    >
      Log In
    </button>
  );
}

function LogoutButton() {
  const { logout } = useAuth0();
  return <button onClick={() => logout()}>Log Out</button>;
}

function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated, isLoading, user, getAccessTokenSilently } =
    useAuth0();

  const getToken = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently({
        authorizationParams: {
          audience: "real-estate-api",
        },
      });

      console.log("Token:", token);
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error getting token:", error);
    }
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {!isAuthenticated ? (
        <LoginButton />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <LogoutButton />
          <div>Hello, {user?.name}</div>
          <button onClick={getToken}>Get Token</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

// Wrap your default export with Auth0Provider
export default function AppWithAuth() {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain="dev-q8w.....uk.auth0.com"
      clientId="vbvi......"
      authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
      }}
    >
      <App />
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
}

Node JS:
auth.ts:
import { auth } from 'express-oauth2-jwt-bearer';

export const jwtCheck = auth({
  issuerBaseURL: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL,
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
});

authenticate.ts:
import httpStatus from 'http-status';

import ApiError from '@utils/handle-api-error';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { UserService } from '@service/user-service';
import { UserRole } from '@common/interface/enums/user.enum';
import { jwtCheck } from '@utils/config/auth';
import { Auth0Request } from '@common/interface/auth.interface';

const userService = new UserService();

export const authMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void => {
  console.log('Received auth header:', req.headers.authorization);
  console.log('Auth header length:', req.headers.authorization?.length);
  jwtCheck(req as Request, res, (err: string) => {
    console.log(err);
    if (err) return next(new ApiError(httpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, 'Unauthorized'));

    const auth = (req as unknown as Auth0Request).auth;

    const userInfo = {
      auth0Id: auth.sub,
      email: auth.email,
    };

    req.user = userInfo;
    next();
  });
};

user-route.ts:
import express from 'express';

import UserController from '@controller/user-controller';

import { validate } from '@middleware/validate';
import { signupSchema, updateUserSchema } from '@utils/validations/user.validation.schema';
import { authMiddleware } from '@middleware/authenticate';

const router = express.Router();

const user = new UserController();

router.post('/register', authMiddleware, validate(signupSchema), user.register);
router.get('/me', authMiddleware, user.getUserById);
router.put('/me', authMiddleware, validate(updateUserSchema), user.updateUserInfo);

export default router;

backend .env:
AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL=https://dev-q8wet.....uk.auth0.com/
AUTH0_AUDIENCE=real-estate-api

execution via postman:
headers tab then add:
Authorization on key, then the value is Bearer {token} (token generated in react app, i copied it from the console)

complete error:
InvalidTokenError: Invalid Compact JWS
    at C:\Users\...\Documents\Pictures\node_modules\express-oauth2-jwt-bearer\dist\index.js:300:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\...\Documents\Pictures\node_modules\express-oauth2-jwt-bearer\dist\index.js:403:24 {
  status: 401,
  statusCode: 401,
  headers: {
    'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer realm="api", error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid Compact JWS"'
  },
  code: 'invalid_token'


So you got a JWT token for your API real-estate-api and verified it is a valid JWT token and then used the token with Postman to call your Express API server and getting this error. Do I understand the issue correctly? Have you tried the reference sample here? https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs/01-authorization

Yes @rsa, and if you check carefully, the one you sent is exactly as my code. Just a different coding approach

i already solved the answer.
The problem is in postman, something is happenning if the format of token when pasting there.
I have tried directly in react js fetch call, i was able to go to the endpoint
